# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ')' while creating the table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever I try to create table in my selected database I get

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

Can anybody tell me whats the error and how to overcome.

What's the error in it ?

```
CREATE TABLE first_name 
( 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that every table needs to have at least a single column.

```
CREATE TABLE users
( 
   id int,
   firstname varchar(255),
   lastname varchar(255)
)
```

Comment: ouch! how foolish of me

Comment: one thing more, I want to concate two strings.. and don't know how.. can yu help plz ?

Comment: You can google that. `concatenate strings` This is different for every DB engine. Looks like you are using SQL-Server.